# Parse Issue. Expected ':'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that was working perfectly on my dev laptop. I took a copy of the project and ran a "pod update", which completed without errors.

Now build fails with this Parse Issue. There are some similar issues reported in other questions, but none that specifically solve this issue.

```
    + (NSString *)avatarUrlForUser:(NSString *)userId {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/avatar.jpeg", HHNetworkManagerUserAvatarURL, userId];
}
```

The error I'm getting is exactly as written in question title.  and it's pointing to HHNetworkManagerUserAvatarURL.

Declarations:

```
#ifdef TESTING
#define HHNetworkManagerHost                      @"127.0.0.1"
#define HHNetworkManagerBaseURL                   @"http://" HHNetworkManagerHost
#else
#define HHNetworkManagerHost                      @"127.0.0.1"
#define HHNetworkManagerBaseURL                   @"https://" HNHetworkManagerHost
#endif
#define HHNetworkManagerApiURL                    HHNetworkManagerBaseURL "/api"
#define HHNetworkManagerRequestPinURL             HHNetworkManagerApiURL "/users/register"
#define HHNetworkManagerVerifyPinURL              HHNetworkManagerApiURL "/users/verify"
#define HHNetworkManagerUploadAvatarURL           HHNetworkManagerApiURL "/users/%@/avatar"
#define HHNetworkManagerUserAvatarURL             HHNetworkManagerApiURL "/users/%@/avatar"**
```

Thanks.

Comment: Quote the error message completely and exactly.

Comment: The title of the question is the exact error.

Comment: Try to do a Clean and build again.

Comment: And how is HHNetworkManagerUserAvatarURL declared?

Comment: Tried a Clean but failed again on run.

Comment: I assume that you added the `**` when you posted -- they're not part of the `#define` statement.

Comment: Your defines for HHNetworkManagerBaseURL are totally bogus.

Comment: And why are there no `@` characters on those character literals??? If you want to substitute a C-string you should use `%s`, not `%@`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `HNHetworkManagerHost` instead of `HHNetworkManagerHost`.

If you do "Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess" you will see this. The error message then comes from this looking like a parameter tag and its not followed by a colon...